# How to dynamically add a parent div (reparent) to a form without losing event handlers

Tags: html, jquery, forms, jquery-events

I want to add a parent div to a form dynamically. No code is required, but here it is (simplified), before someone complains:

```
    <form id="fileupload" style="position:absolute;left:100px;top:100px;"  method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
     <input type="text" name="ram1"  />
     <button type="submit" >Start Submit</button>
    </form>
```

I want a parent div as in:

```
   <div ....>
        <form...>
        </form>
   </div>
```

But in so doing, I do not want event handlers on inner form elements to be lost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$("#fileupload").wrap("<div ..>")
```

Refer http://api.jquery.com/wrap/ for more options

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/GsFA3/)**

Answer (score 1):

if you want to wrap the matched elements into individual div's then use wrap else wrapAll to put all the matched elements into one div

```
$("#fileupload").wrap( "<div class='new'/>");
```

Answer (score 1):

Try it

```
$("#fileupload").wrap("<div></div>");
```